# How to zoom very close for mesh repairing

Tags: mesh

I have 2 queries here

1. How to zoom very close for mesh repairing?
   If I zoom in to far it moves past the hole.

[image]

2. What is the best tool for repair this hole/gap? I plan to use the fill tool via ALT+F

Comment: Hi :). You can zoom more precisely by holding down Ctrl and holding down and dragging the mousewheel.

Comment: ... where 'zooming' is actually dollying. For a true zoom, you can go into the 'View' tab of the N panel and change the focal length of the viewport camera

Comment: select one of the edges or verts and press "." on your numpad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't that it's zooming too far per se, it's that it's not zooming on what you want. You need to change your focus.

With the area you want to focus selected, press numpad <kbd>.</kbd>
This will move your view such that the focus is the selection. Zooming in and out will now keep the focus.

Note that panning the view (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>mmb</kbd>) will move the focus

Finally, if you want to move your focus manually but precisely, I suggest going into the front(<kbd>1</kbd>), right(<kbd>3</kbd>), or top(<kbd>7</kbd>) views and panning the view there while gradually zooming.

Answer (score 1):

You can zoom in by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse3</kbd> (Scroll/Wheel) and then moving you mouse "up" and "down".

If your view starts clipping when you get close to the mesh just press <kbd>N</kbd> and go to "View" to change the "Clip Start".

To repair the hole I believe the best way is using the fill toll by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: you mean Ctrl+RMB? I just get a lasso selection with that command. Your clipping and repair suggestion works.

Comment: Ctrl + Pressing the scroll/wheel